# Prism WPF Login Window Close

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm using prism and I'm trying to close the login window once the login is successful and show the main window. I found the link below to get an idea how I could do it and I changed it to make it work with prism.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/581554/WPFplusLoginplusinplusMVVMplusIssue

An event is triggered from the view model when the login is matched.

My login window actually closes once the login is successful but the main window doesn't appear.

Here's my code

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var login = new Login();
        var loginVM = new LoginViewModel();

        loginVM.LoginCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();

            login.Close();
        };
        login.DataContext = loginVM;
        login.ShowDialog();
    }


}
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
class Bootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper
    {

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same solution. It is working as per the expectations.

What I did is

App.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }
```

BootStrapper

```
    class Bootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper
    {
         protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
         {
             return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
         }

         public override void Run(bool runWithDefaultConfiguration)
         {
             base.Run(true);
             AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
         }

         protected override void InitializeShell()
         {
             var login = new Views.Login.LoginView();
             var loginVM = new LoginViewModel();

             loginVM.LoginCompleted += (sender, args) =>
             {
                   Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
                   login.Close();
             };
             login.DataContext = loginVM;
             login.ShowDialog();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, however, Im getting an error with the following line:           AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure(); 
It doesnt exist in the current context.
How do I fix it? Thanks

Comment: I am using Automapper in our project, hence the line.